# How to pass uninitialized variable address in Unsafe Rust

Tags: rust

Following code throws an error

***borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `ires`***

```
pub fn new(t: QueryType) -> QueryObject
{
    unsafe {
        let mut ires: u32;
        gl::GenQueries(1, &mut ires as *mut u32);
        
        let res = QueryObject {
            index: ires,
            qtype: t as u32,
            status: QueryStatus::Inactive as u32,
        };

        return res;
    }
}
```

How should I pass the variable address without initializing variable `ires`

Comment: Nothing expects to be handed uninitialized memory, so if you're going to pass it around at all, you have to be *extremely* careful. It is probably just better to initialize it to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) to tell the compiler the bit pattern of a value may not be a valid bit pattern.

```rust
let ires = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
gl::GenQueries(1, ires.as_mut_ptr());
let ires = unsafe { ires.assume_init() };
```

By using `assume_init`, you're telling the compiler that you've checked that `ires` is a valid initialized value. If you didn't, undefined behavior can occur. In this case, if you're sure 100% that `gl::GenQueries` will not try to read this value, giving it uninitialized memory *should* be fine. I say "should" because it is [still a debate](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/71) whether uninitialized integers are valid integers.

Be really careful with uninitialized memory. If you want to play with it, I suggest you to check out this [blog post](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2019/07/14/uninit.html).

Comment: "If you didn't, undefined behavior can occur". `uninit().assume_init()` *is* undefined behavior.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed It isn't as long as you never read the value. If the function never actually reads it and juste initializes it (without using the `&mut `, that would drop the value), I think it is sound.

Comment: AFAIK, it's undecided yet. It's better to call `assume_init` only after the initialization was already done, even with primitives.

Comment: Fixed. The `.as_mut_ptr()` function was actually what I was looking for. Now the code is `100%` sound as long as `gl::getQueries` properly initializes `ires`.

Comment: That's a lot of code, to save 1 clock cycle, for something that would already be rarely called :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it's because Rust can't guarantee that [`gl::GenQueries()`](https://docs.rs/gl/0.14.0/gl/fn.GenQueries.html) doesn't attempt to read from `ires` before it is initialized. Therefore you must always initialize before you attempt to borrow.

To resolve the issue, you just have to initialize it with `0`. You can also simplify `&mut ires as *mut u32` to just `&mut ires`.

```rust
let mut ires: u32 = 0;
gl::GenQueries(1, &mut ires);
```

Even if you were able to bypass "borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable". Then you would subsequently just receive "use of possibly-uninitialized variable". As there's no guarantees that [`gl::GenQueries()`](https://docs.rs/gl/0.14.0/gl/fn.GenQueries.html) initialized `ires`.

The cost of initializing a `u32` is negligible. However, if you insist then check out [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html).